# Best practice: Shared Folders Server 2008

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, sync, windows-server-2008-r2

I like the idea of remote profiles that users keep a local copy of their profile on their machine. So if the server malfunctions they'd still have access to their files.

Now, is there something similar (sync local folder when user logs in and sync server folder again when user logs out) like the remote profiles? Because I also have a public folder "company" different users can access. I still want them to have access to those files even if the server should be down.

I know there is Sync Center but is there something else? Preferrably managable on the Server?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a server side solution, I would give you the advice to consider setting up a second file server and configure a DFS replication between them for your "Company" folder.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753479(v=WS.10).aspx